# mysql NOW() return wrong value whereas global timezone is set +00:00

Tags: mysql, timezone-offset

since 2 weeks I puzzled over timezone issue, everything working fine on my localhost BUT it returns wrong value on dedicated server. Let me tell what i have done so far.

First set global timezone by below query: ( Super privilege both on localhost and server )

```
 SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+00:00';
```

now run below query  to cross check whatever done

```
SELECT NOW(),@@global.time_zone AS gtz,@@session.time_zone AS stz,
       TIMEDIFF(NOW(), CONVERT_TZ( NOW() , @@session.time_zone ,  '+00:00' ) )
       AS OFFSET;
```

but it display different results on local and dedicated server

#### on localhost (192.168.x.x) mysql version : 5.5.8

```
+---------------------+--------+--------+----------+
| NOW()               | gtz    | stz    | OFFSET   |
+---------------------+--------+--------+----------+
| 2012-07-02 07:06:55 | +00:00 | +00:00 | 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+--------+--------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### on dedicated server (182.168.x.x) mysql version :5.1.53-log

```
+---------------------+--------+--------+----------+
| NOW()               | gtz    | stz    | OFFSET   |
+---------------------+--------+--------+----------+
| 2012-07-02 12:37:59 | +00:00 | +00:00 | 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+--------+--------+----------+
```

My question is

> why **NOW()** gives  wrong time ( above is IST )  whereas
>   timezone is set to +00:00 ?

**side note :**

I run below query

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%time%zone%';
```

#### on localhost

```
+------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value               |
+------------------+---------------------+
| system_time_zone | India Standard Time |
| time_zone        | +00:00              |
+------------------+---------------------+
```

#### on server

```
+------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value               |
+------------------+---------------------+
| system_time_zone | GMT+5               |
| time_zone        | +00:00              |
+------------------+---------------------+
```

> does this will affect the result? OR
>
> is there any bug in earlier version of mysql ?

please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When calling `NOW()` (and related functions), MySQL converts the computer's system clock to the session timezone:

- If the system clock is set to `12:30+05:30` and the session timezone is `+00:00`, the result will be `07:00`.
- If the system clock is set to `17:30+05:00` and the session timezone is `+00:00`, the result will be `12:30`.

However, one can 'fool' MySQL into thinking that the system clock is in a different timezone to that which the operating system believes by using the [`--timezone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqld-safe.html#option_mysqld_safe_timezone) command line argument to [*`mysqld_safe`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqld-safe.html):

- If the system clock is set to `17:30+10:30` and the session timezone is `+00:00`, but MySQL was started in such a way specifying that the system clock should be understood to be `GMT+5`, the result will be the same as the second bullet above.

You should therefore check:

1. That the timezone of the system clock reconciles with the value given in the `system_time_zone` system variable (if it doesn't, ensure that you are not specifying a `--timezone` argument to *`mysqld_safe`* and that there was no `TZ` environment variable set when *`mysqld_safe`* was invoked);
2. That the system clock is reporting the correct time in its specified timezone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i really failed to relate this answer with my question? what changes i need to do?

Comment: will you provide me any referel link for more information. how do i achieve  my solution by using above solution?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to restart mysqld after altering timezone of System..

The Global time zone of MySQL takes timezone of System. When you change any such attribute of system, you just need a restart of Mysqld.

That's it.

Comment: This is the much better answer than the accepted answer.  For those on Ubuntu: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-or-change-timezone-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Answer (score 0):

1) Change your system time and timezone, if necessary.
2) Open mysql console and put in your timezone, smth like this: SET GLOBAL time_zone = "+04:00";
3) Restart mysql.

Answer (score -1):

i have tested- 
SET time_zone='+05:30'; it is working,but i dont have global permission so you try by setting server time +05:30 ->
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+05:30';